# how to find all if the array is empty, mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i am trying to do some queries to my db... but i am new in mongodb and i dont know what operator i have to use, or maybe i just do not know how to do it.

i have a collection like this.

```
const userSchema= new Schema({
    user: { type: String },
    object: { type: String }
})
```

then i receive in my server a query like this

```
{
users: ['John', 'Michael', 'Peter'],
objects: ['Object1','Object2','Object3','Object4', 'Object5']
}
```

so.. in my controller i do this to find...

```
userModel.find({ user: { $in: req.body.users}, object: { $in: req.body.objects})
        .then((users)=>{
          res.json(users)
        })
```

Ok, this is working... but, in the case that one of the arrays Users or Objects is empty, it doesn't find nothing... so, how i can handle it? there is any operator that can find all if the array is empty or something?

for example.. if the query comes like this.

```
{
users: ['John', 'Michael', 'Peter'],
objects: []
}
```

i would like to find the users in my Users array even if i dont receive any object.

Any help? thank you in advance

Comment: I think you are looking for the $or operator

Comment: with the $or operator i dont get the result that i expect, because it finds all users and all objects in the model and i just want to find the users that has those objects... damn sorry maybe i am not explaining it well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create custom match criteria

```
const query = {
  fieldName: { $gte: ..., $lte: ... }
}
if (req.body.users.length > 0) {
  query.users = req.body.users
}
if (req.body.objects.length > 0) {
  query.objects = req.body.objects
}

userModel.find(query).then((users) => {
  console.log(users)
})
```

Comment: but.. if req.body.users and objects is an array??

Comment: So what? Please try it and then ask a question.

Comment: thank you, it works! but i have other question... in case that i want to filter in a date range... i am using { $gte : date: req.body.dateFrom, $lt: date: req.body.dateTo } ... How can i add it to this query object?

Comment: Add that criteria in the first part inside `query` `const query = { ... }`

Comment: mmm it is not finding well.. i think something is wrong with my sintax... where should i add the operators $gte and  $lt?

Comment: i already have, query.users , query.objects, query.dateFrom , query.dateTo